# UDP Image transfer works depending on network

Tags: java, sockets, udp

my program has a client/server, where the server sends a live stream of images from a webcam to the client using UDP. The server is at my work, while the client can be accessed online from anywhere. 
The sending and receiving of images works perfectly fine --sometimes. I noticed that, depending where the client is, they may or may not be able to receive images. Ive had several people from several different locations access the online client, and several of them can receive images perfectly, while others cannot receive any.

The ones that cannot receive images, can however receive messages from the server using that same port.

To ensure that it was not something wrong with a computer. I tested the client with my laptop at work, and was able to receive images. However when I am connected to my home network(with the same laptop) I cannot. I can only think the problem has something to do with different networks as that is the only thing that changed.

SendImage code:

```
public void sendImage()
{
      //  get image as bytes for UDP communication
     ByteArrayOutputStream baStream =null;

     try {
        //compresses image file and returns a ByteArrayOutputStream
            baStream =compress(cap.getOneFrame(),0.1f); 
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
     //byte array to send via udp
       packet = baStream.toByteArray();

      try {

        sendPacket=(new DatagramPacket(packet,packet.length,IPAddress,port));
        System.out.println(sendPacket.getLength());
        serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
      } 
      catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```

Retrieve image code:

```
public void receiveImage()
{
    //receive the incoming packet
    DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length); 
    try {
        clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
    }
     catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //retrieve the data from the packet
    byte[] data = receivePacket.getData();
      // Read incoming data into a ByteArrayInputStream
      ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream( data );
      try 
    {
          //convert to buffered image
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(bais);
        if (img != null) 
        {
                gui.getBottomCamPanel().setImage(img);
                gui.getBottomCamPanel().repaint();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe they're on unreliable networks and some of the UDP packets are getting lost or delivered out of order?

Comment: Possible, but my home connection is pretty reliable (very rarely throttles). Is it possible for a router/ISP to block UDP packets greater than a certain size?

Comment: It's not so much that ISPs choose to block by size, but that the underlying transmission technology will impose inherent MTU size limits (for packets going over VPNs the overall size is reduced by the wrapper overhead, and technologies like PPPoE for DSL may have a lower MTU than your LAN). How big are the packets you're dealing with?

Comment: Hmm I see. They average at 6000-7000 bytes. Well under the 65536 limit

Comment: Well, that's your problem. You cannot expect a usable MTU of more than around 1400 bytes for an arbitrary internet connection.

Comment: Alright, I'll try splitting it up over multiple packets.
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, it depends on the **type of network**. More specifically, different **Network Address Translation(NAT)** schemes used in different networks lead to this situation. The reason for the client not receiving the images is that the **firewall is blocking the UDP packets**.

The router's firewall allows outgoing UDP packets but blocks incoming UDP packets by default.
It allows incoming packets only from sources where a UDP packet was sent earlier and that created a mapping in its routing table. This is overall a typical process varying for different types of NAT.

Depending on the type of NAT being used by the router to which the client is connected, the **mapping** of **internal IP and port**(*those which your system is using*) to the **external IP and port**(*those alloted by the router to connect to the internet*) are different.

You need to understand the different types of NATs(or NAPT) and how these mappings are created.

There is **no universal solution available** to solve this problem. To some extent **UDP hole punching** solves this but that too **doesn't works for symmetric NAT**.

Read more about NAT schemes. Some of the sources are:

[Network Address Translation RFC 1631](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1631.txt)

[NAT behavioral requirements for Unicast UDP RFC 4787](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4787)

[NAT](http://computernetworkingnotes.com/wan-protocols-hdlc-ppp-frame-really-nat-pat/nat.html)

[Types of NAT](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/types-of-network-address-translation.html)